# Please help identify the LEGO Set from attached pics

Tags: set-identification

Got this, may not be completed. Please help identify the Set#.[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the vehicles from [70006-1: Cragger's Command Ship](https://brickset.com/sets/70006-1/Cragger-s-Command-Ship)

[image]
[image]